# React-Native Text input prevents scrolling

Tags: react-native

I have react native screen with single line TextInput:

```
<ScrollView>
    ...
    <TextInput />
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

When I try to scroll the through the screen and my initial tap lands on TextInput, screen scrolling doesn't work. It almost tries to scroll inside the TextInput, but there is nothing to scroll. Here is what the text input looks like:

```
<TextInput
    style={{...styles.rowInput, color: theme.textColor}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({name: text})}
    selectTextOnFocus={false}
    autoCapitalize="words"
    numberOfLines={1}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCorrect={false}
    placeholder="Enter Your Name"
    placeholderTextColor={borderColor}
    maxLength={24} />
```

Any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: can add your styles.rowInput

Comment: Could you resolve the issue? I'm just having the same one!

Answer (score 0):

It related to `ScrollView` and you can fix this by setting `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` to 'Handled'. Try this..

```
<ScrollView
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
        ...
        <TextInput />
        ...
</ScrollView>
```